# How do I send Formik Form Submission data sent to private email

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, submission

I am using formik and react to handle a form on the website for a personal project I have started. I am trying to figure out how to get data entered into the form to be emailed / sent to me in order to use it. How can I do this?

```
const formik = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
        // values removed to keep brief
      },
      validationSchema: Yup.object({
        // values removed to keep brief
      }),
      onSubmit: values => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      },
    });
```

Currently I have it so that on submit it gives the user an alert of the object... I want it so that I get emailed the very same message of the alert!

Comment: You need to share specific details of what service/module/language/stack you are using to send emails. This isn’t enough information to help move you forward.

Comment: You need backend to send email, you can not send email from the frontend

Answer (score 0):

To those who want to achieve the same objective as me, **I have a solution for react and vanilla js**. I have found a solution using emailjs. This is an extension that allows you to email forms with javascript. The docs are a lot more detailed than this and very straightforward: [documentation](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/)

I imported the module and initilised it with my own personal user id obtained after registering [here](https://dashboard.emailjs.com/sign-up)

```
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
emailjs.init('userID')
```

Then I added this onSubmit function into my react form module

```
function sendEmail() {
    let templateParams = formik.values

    emailjs.send([serviceId], [templateId], templateParams)
      .then((result) => {
          console.log('SUCCESS!', result.status, result.text)  //This is if you still want the page to reload (since e.preventDefault() cancelled that behavior) 
      }, (error) => {
          console.log('FAILED...', error);
      });
  }
```

`formik.values` is an object of values entered into the form by the user. Formik is a great tool for making forms in react [here is their website](https://formik.org/)

The `serviceId` and `templateId` arguments are strings and are also obtained when signing up to emailjs.

The third argument (`templateParams) is just the object that is returned to you and sent in the email.

**If you are using vanilla js and want to do same thing**... use `emailjs.sendForm` instead of `emailjs.send`!

```
function sendEmail() {
    emailjs.sendForm([serviceId], [templateId], [querySelector])
      .then((result) => {
          console.log('SUCCESS!', result.status, result.text)  //This is if you still want the page to reload (since e.preventDefault() cancelled that behavior) 
      }, (error) => {
          console.log('FAILED...', error);
      });
  }
```

Where `querySelector` is a string of the id / class of your form ie.

```
<form onSubmit='sendEmail' id="formId">
  labels...
  inputs...
<form>
```

in this case, [querySelector] = '#formId'